# Macro for filtering and transposing

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, transpose

I have this data

```
Module Process
A      P1
A      P2
A      P3
B      P5
B      P7
C      P4
C      P6
C      P8
```

I want to filter out first value in the filter and put the respective data in in rows like this

```
Module Process
A      P1  |  P2  |  P3
B      P5  |  P7  |
C      P4  |  P6  |  P8
```

My macro is not yet ready but here it is

```
Sub Macro1()
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$415").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
Range("B2:B4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

However I dont know if the next time when i run the macro, it will be A, B or C, it will be something different than these. So how can i choose whatever the first text is as a filter?

Also I have two more questions.
How do we repeat the filtering process until the last text in the filter (in this case C) is reached?

Currently It is selecting range B2:B4 for transpose, I want to make it dynamic as in from first cell of B as per the applied filter to last cell of B for that particular filter. How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the data on column `Module`. Use the macro recorder if you don't know how to do it in VBA.
2. Create a new blank sheet, call it `Report`. Set `dest_Line = 1`, `dest_Value = ""`
3. Iterate on the data sheet from row 2 to the end of data.

   - When you get a new valuein column `Module` (that is, the value in column `Module` is different from `dest_Value`):

     - Set `dest_Value` to the value in column `Module`.
     - Increment `dest_line`, copy the value from colum `Module` in line `dest_Line` column 1 and the value from colum `Process` in column 2; set `dest_Column = 3`.
   - Otherwise it is the same as the previous value:

     - Copy the value from column `Process` in line `dest_Line` column `dest_Column`; increment `dest_Column`.

If instead of a new blank sheet you want to use some space on the same sheet then adjust the starting points of `dest_Line` and `dest_Column`.